# Regex Matcher Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to the Language.

I am trying to extract all characters till the escape character (\r).

I tried

```
text = "abcde\r"

text.match(/(.*)(\r)/)
```

I tried the same with gsub and gsub!. None are working.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: `\r` isn't "*the* escape character", it's "*an* escaped character". Terminology is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-slice) passing the regular expression and the match to get. The `1` represents the first (and in this case the only) match.

```
text = "abcde\r"
text.slice(/(.*)\r/, 1)
 => "abcde"
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I had issue with the irb terminal. It wasn't printing the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be dealing with the specific case of lines from a file, and you want to remove the line ending, you can use `chop` or `chomp`. For example:

```
require 'pp'

lines = [
  "hello",
  "there\r",
  "how\r\n",
  "are you?"
]

lines.each do |line|
  pp line
  pp line.chomp
  puts '---'
end
```

Results in:

```
"hello"
"hello"
---
"there\r"
"there"
---
"how\r\n"
"how"
---
"are you?"
"are you?"
---
```

Comment: Be careful using `chop` as it indiscriminately removes the last character: `'foo'.chop # => "fo"`. Both `rstrip` and `chomp` are the most used ways to do this.